# Calculating Number of Consecutive Days using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

The below code calculates the number of days with heavy precipitation with dates. However I don't know how can I compute the number of consecutive days from the final result. For instance, I want to know that how many consecutive days experienced heavy rainfall.

Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0b25766495d1f1a355fbaf3973b97012

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var temporalCollection = function(collection, start, count, interval, units){
  
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)),units);
    
    return collection
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate).mean()
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis());
    
  }));
  
};

var startYear = '2020'; 
var endYear = '2021';

var pr = function(img){
  return img.select('precipitationCal').clip(table).multiply(24)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var precipitationGPM = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06")
.filterDate(startYear, endYear)
.filterBounds(table)
.map(pr);


var prDaily = temporalCollection(precipitationGPM, startYear, 365, 1, 'days')
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,8,'month'))
.map(function(img){
  
  var pday = img.multiply(24.0);
  
  var pMean = pday.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 1000,
    geometry: table
  }).getNumber('precipitationCal');
  
  return pday
  .set('pMean',pMean)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});


print(prDaily);


// extreme evemts analysis
// pr >= 10 mm/day as heavy rainfall
// pr >= 20 mm/day as very heavy rainfall



var heavyRain = prDaily
.filterMetadata('pMean','greater_than', 9.9)



print('Heavy Rainy Days:'+startYear, heavyRain.size());


//----------------------------------------------------------------

// put all dates in a list
var dates = ee.List(heavyRain.aggregate_array("system:time_start"))
    .map(function(d) { return ee.Date(d)});

// print a list with dates
print(dates);
```

Comment: See this article: https://medium.com/google-earth/runs-with-arrays-400de937510a

Comment: I know about this method: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d9164441ac83279262ef506a6197bca5
However it is for 0 value precipitation but I don't know how can I set another threshold like less than 2 instead of 0 mm for precipitation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For applying Gorelick's approach (Runs with Arrays) to precipitation values different of 0, you only have to try with 1 values generated with the specified threshold (9.9 in your case) for daily precipitation sequence. So, you only need to change a few lines in original Gorelick's code: prepending a 0 to the **difference** array and mask **wetRunStarts** and **wetRunLengths** (I also renamed the variables for an obvious reason) with 1 instead 0.

As you didn't generate a daily precipitation sequence based in the threshold, you need one. It is easily obtained with following function:

```
var prDaily_lst = prDaily.toList(prDaily.size());

var precipitation = prDaily_lst.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number.parse(ee.Image(ele).get('pMean')).gt(9.9), 1, 0);
  
});
```

You also need a dates sequence for pairing them with **wetRunStarts** list resulting of adapting Gorelick's code. It looks as follows.

```
var dates = prDaily.aggregate_array("system:time_start");

var dates = dates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });
```

Complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1b2adfd245ecc75f15ba88745f53825d) looks as follows:

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var temporalCollection = function(collection, start, count, interval, units){
  
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)),units);
    
    return collection
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate).mean()
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis());
    
  }));
  
};

var startYear = '2020'; 
var endYear = '2021';

var pr = function(img){
  return img.select('precipitationCal').clip(table).multiply(24)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var precipitationGPM = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_V06")
  .filterDate(startYear, endYear)
  .filterBounds(table)
  .map(pr);

var prDaily = temporalCollection(precipitationGPM, startYear, 365, 1, 'days')
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,8,'month'))
  .map(function(img){
  
    var pday = img.multiply(24.0);
  
    var pMean = pday.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      scale: 1000,
      geometry: table
    }).getNumber('precipitationCal');
  
  return pday
    .set('pMean',pMean)
    .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
});

print("prDaily", prDaily);

// extreme evemts analysis
// pr >= 10 mm/day as heavy rainfall
// pr >= 20 mm/day as very heavy rainfall

var heavyRain = prDaily
  .filterMetadata('pMean','greater_than', 9.9);

//print('Heavy Rainy Days:' + startYear, heavyRain.size());

var prDaily_lst = prDaily.toList(prDaily.size());

var precipitation = prDaily_lst.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number.parse(ee.Image(ele).get('pMean')).gt(9.9), 1, 0);
  
});

print('precipitation', precipitation);

//----------------------------------------------------------------

// put all dates in a list
var dates = prDaily.aggregate_array("system:time_start");

var dates = dates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,10);
  });

// print a list with dates
print("dates", dates);

// We're only working with a single axis: #0
var axis = 0;

// computes the foward difference of an array.
var forwardDifference = function(array) {
  var left = array.slice(axis, 0, -1);
  var right = array.slice(axis, 1);
  return left.subtract(right);
};

var precipitation = ee.Array(precipitation);

var difference = forwardDifference(precipitation);
difference = ee.Array.cat([[0], difference], axis);   // Prepend a 0 to the difference array.

//print("difference", difference);

var length1 = precipitation.length().get([0]);   // How long is the data array?
var indexList = ee.List.sequence(0, length1.subtract(1));  // A list of sequential numbers.

var runStarts = ee.Array(indexList).mask(difference.neq(0));
var runLengths = forwardDifference(ee.Array.cat([runStarts, [length1]], 0)).multiply(-1);

var runValues = precipitation.mask(difference.neq(0));

var wetRunStarts = runStarts.mask(runValues.eq(1));
var wetRunLengths = runLengths.mask(runValues.eq(1));

var datesWetRunStarts = wetRunStarts.toList().map(function (ele) {
  
  return dates.get(ele);
  
});

print("wetRunStarts", wetRunStarts);
print("datesWetRunStarts", datesWetRunStarts);
print("wetRunLengths", wetRunLengths);

var maxIndex = wetRunLengths.argmax();

print(wetRunStarts.get(maxIndex).format("The first day of the longest wet run is day: %d"));
print(wetRunLengths.get(maxIndex).format("The length of the longest run of wet days is: %d days"));
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got result of following image.

[image]

All printed results were corroborated carefully and they were as expected.

**Editing Note:**

For setting a range between 5 to 10 mm you need to generate precipitation ones sequence as follows:

```
var precipitation = prDaily_lst.map(function (ele) {
  
  return ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Number.parse(ee.Image(ele).get('pMean')).gte(2)
                          .and(ee.Number.parse(ee.Image(ele).get('pMean')).lte(5)), 1, 0);
  
});
```

Complete code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9dd426bb32c3b2343579bc44e42435db) and, after running it, I got following result.

[image]

You can corroborate that code also works as expected by using **precipitation_val** variable.

Comment: You right it works. How can I set a range for rainfall threshold. For instance when I set a range between 5 to 10 mm returns error.

Comment: The key is how to generate ones sequence by using that range. You can see my **Editing Note** where it can be watched how it can be done.

Comment: It works, appreciated.